# Ubuntu 14.10 no sound on Thinkpad T60

Tags: 14.10

My laptop is Thinkpad T60 and i use external speaker. one month ago, I install Ubuntu 14.10, after software update, everything is ok and sound work fine. 7 days ago I installed Windows 7 and then I reinstalled Ubuntu 14.10, but sound doesn't work. I tried to install some times again (about 10 times include Ubuntu 13.10, 14.04) but still sound doesn't work.

```
 **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: AD1981 Analog [AD1981 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 1: AD1981 Digital [AD1981 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Answer (score 1):

We have to enable the volume control buttons:

```
sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

**and add the line:**

```
cp /sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/hotkey_all_mask /sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/hotkey_mask
```

Comment: thank you, i do that and then i restart computer but no sound.

Answer (score 1):

OR,
**1.Open a terminal. (The quickest way is the Ctrl-Alt-T shortcut)**

Enter “alsamixer” and press the Enter key.

You will now see a user interface like below.

no sound

In this user interface, you can do the following:

```
Select your correct sound card using F6 and select F5 to see recording controls as well
Move around with left and right arrow keys.
Increase and decrease volume with up and down arrow keys.
Mute/Unmute with the “M” key. An “MM” means muted, and “OO” means unmuted.
Exit from alsamixer with the Esc key.
```

A caveat here: When you mute or unmute something, pulseaudio might pick it up and mute and unmute other controls, as well as PulseAudio’s main mute.
**2. Reinstall Alsa and Pulse Audio**

Try to reinstall pulse audio and Alsa, open terminal and enter the following commands:

Purge Alsa and Pulse audio using the command:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
```

Now install again Alsa and Pulse Audio:

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
```

Then, reload Alsa:

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

Done. Check now the sound if it is working, if not, try step 4.
**3. Install Ubuntu Audio Development Team Driver**

Note: This PPA is not updated to 14.04 yet.

Upgrading your sound drivers may fix the nosound issue, you will need to make sure to uninstall the previous override before trying a new one.

Open terminal and enter the following PPA:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```